# Inline edit sends nothing to controller

Tags: magento2.3, inline-editor

In creating a grid with **editable columns** by a **inline editor**; and the editor sends nothing to the **controller** i don't know where the problem is. Its appearing always: {"messages":["Please correct the data sent."],"error":true} cause the editor send a empty array to the controller i leave the code here:

listing.xml

```
<columns name="spinner_columns">
    <settings>
        <editorConfig>
            <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_market_listing.test_market_listing.spinner_columns.ids</param>
            <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
            <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
            <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="sellermania/market/inlineEdit"/>
                <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </param>
        </editorConfig>

        <childDefaults>
            <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_market_listing.test_market_listing.spinner_columns_editor</item>
                <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </param>
        </childDefaults>
    </settings>
    <selectionsColumn name="ids" sortOrder="10">
        <settings>
            <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
        </settings>
    </selectionsColumn>

    <column name="entity_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="code">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Code</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="store_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

</columns>
```

And here the controller code:

```
<?php

namespace test\test\Controller\Adminhtml\Market;

class InlineEdit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $jsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {


        $error = false;
        $messages = [];
        $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();

        $postItems = $this->getRequest()->getParam('items', []);
        if (!($this->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax') && count($postItems))) {
            return $resultJson->setData([
                'messages' => [__('Please correct the data sent.')],
                'error' => true,
            ]);
        }
        foreach (array_keys($postItems) as $modelid) {

            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('test\test\Model\Marketplace')->load($modelid);
            try {
                $model->setData(array_merge($model->getData(), $postItems[$modelid]));
                $model->save();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $messages[] = "[Entity ID: {$modelid}]  {$e->getMessage()}";
                $error = true;
            }
        }



        return $resultJson->setData([
            'messages' => $messages,
            'error' => $error
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you passing the data, as a json?

Comment: magefms yes inline editor is suposed to do it in json as post, but when i do the getrequest on the controller i get nothing

Comment: have you tried `$this->getRequest()->getPost()` ? instead of `getParam()`

Comment: since you want to read data passed via POST method

Comment: Ive tried getPost and $postItems still empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, use `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http`, and get post contents using its `request` instance injected in the constructor:

EDIT: Modify your **`listing.xml`** to be like this:

```
<columns name="spinner_columns">
    <settings>
        <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_market_listing.test_market_listing.spinner_columns.ids</item>
            <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
            <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="sellermania/market/inlineEdit"/>
                <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </item>
     <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_market_listing.test_market_listing.spinner_columns_editor</item>
        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
        </item>
       </item>
    </settings>
    <selectionsColumn name="ids" sortOrder="10">
        <settings>
            <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
        </settings>
    </selectionsColumn>

    <column name="entity_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="code">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Code</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="store_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store ID</item>

            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

</columns>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace test\test\Controller\Adminhtml\Market;

class InlineEdit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http  */
    protected $request;

    protected $jsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {


        $error = false;
        $messages = [];
        $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();

        $postItems = $this->request->getContent();
        $postData = json_decode($postItems);
        if (isset($postData)) {
            return $resultJson->setData([
                'messages' => [__('Please correct the data sent.')],
                'error' => true,
            ]);
        }
        foreach (array_keys($postData) as $modelid) {

            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('test\test\Model\Marketplace')->load($modelid);
            try {
                $model->setData(array_merge($model->getData(), $postItems[$modelid]));
                $model->save();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $messages[] = "[Entity ID: {$modelid}]  {$e->getMessage()}";
                $error = true;
            }
        }



        return $resultJson->setData([
            'messages' => $messages,
            'error' => $error
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given. So $postItems is still empty; dont know why im not getting the edit parameters of the column.

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: ive modified it but the xml estructure gives this error:

Comment: market_listing.xml" is invalid:
Element 'item': This element is not expected.
Line: 49

Comment: after <settings> cant be a item or argument i think

Comment: Ive fixed the xml error and still the same problems, nothing is being send to the controller: Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: can you post your new xml

Comment: I mean the new listing.xml

Comment: ask is already edited

Comment: try new updated answer

Comment: The xml has an error: Element 'item': This element is not expected.
Line: 49

after <settings> cant be a <item>

Comment: Error is weird settings is on line 20+ only